# split on non-consistent string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have these value

```
['book_1', 'reader_2', 'book_borrower_3', 'book_reader_borrower_4']
```

How do I get their numberic number which appended after the last `_`? I can't do `str.split('_')[1]`, because some of the value does have 2 `_`, either can I use slice to get last character, what if the numberic value is more than 1 character.

Comment: Try `.split('_').pop()`

Comment: var numbers = values.map(value.split("_").pop())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
let values = ['book_1', 'reader_2', 'book_borrower_3', 'book_reader_borrower_4'];
let numbers = values.map(value => value.split("_").pop());
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex for this: `/_(\d+)$/`

```js
const regex = /_(\d+)$/;
const books = ['book_1', 'reader_2', 'book_borrower_3', 'book_reader_borrower_4']

const numbers = books.map(book => book.match(regex)[1]);
console.log(numbers);
```

The regex works like this:

```
 _                 match a single _

  (                  start a matching group
    \d+                match one or more digits
  )                  close matching group
$                  assert end of string
```

You don't necessarily need the beginning `_`, it's up to you if that fits your usecase

Answer (score 3):

Using [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

```js
let values = ['book_1', 'reader_2', 'book_borrower_3', 'book_reader_borrower_4']

let result = values.map(str => str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('_') + 1))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could match the last digits.

```js
var array = ['book_1', 'reader_2', 'book_borrower_3', 'book_reader_borrower_4'],
    numbers = array.map(s => +s.match(/\d+$/));

console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

So either you use pop method on split method like

```
var digit = str.split('_').pop()
```

OR get the last element from the array returned by split

```
var spStr = str.split('_');
var digit = spStr[spStr.length-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/lastIndexOf) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/slice) functions

```js
const arr = ['book_1', 'reader_2', 'book_borrower_3', 'book_reader_borrower_4'];

const strs = arr.map(str => {
  let i = str.lastIndexOf("_");
  return str.slice(i+1);
});

console.log(strs);
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this below Code Snip

```js
var values = ['book_1', 'reader_2', 'book_borrower_3', 'book_reader_borrower_4'];
for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  console.log(values[i].substring(values[i].lastIndexOf('_') + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Philips regex solution and @Aurel Bílý solutions are great. Here is a solution that is kind of fun

```
const books = ['book_1', 'reader_2', 'book_borrower_3', 'book_reader_borrower_4'];
const bookNumbers = books.map((book) => book.split('_').reverse()[0]);
```

Admittedly not the most performant, but yet another way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You could join first, and then `.match(/\d+(?=,|$)/g)` to get all the digits in the string delimeted by `,`:

```js
const books = ['book_1', 'reader_2', 'book_borrower_3', 'book_reader_borrower_4'];
const res = books.join().match(/\d+(?=,|$)/g);

console.log(res);
```